# webpack watch mode is random

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm using webpack with Angular2 as explained in [this article](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html). It works quite OK but I have an issue with "webpack-dev-server". Its watching mode is quite erratic. When I make modification in a file (the index.html for example), sometimes it rebundles my package, something not... I have no way of isolating a behaviour as something two exact same modification don't produce the same result (sometimes it bundles, sometimes not).

My configuration files are the same as the ones in the article provided above. It's quite annoying because, for now, I have to relaunch the command every time...

webpack version: 1.13.2

webpack-dev-server version: 1.16.1

Comment: Ah! The problem was actually not due to webkacp-dev-server but my IDE. As I think that other people could experienced the same issue, here's the solution: I'm using WebStorm and I have to deactivate the "safe write" mode as explained here: https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#working-with-editors-ides-supporting-safe-write

Comment: Thank you! I had the same problem and this fixed it for me.

You should put this as an answer.